# Command line or powershell command to list IE add-ons

Tags: browser, browser-addons, internet-explorer-8, powershell

Is there a cmd line or powershell command that will list all the add-ons that are installed in IE8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [Sysinternals Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) comes with a command-line tool:

```
autorunsc -a i
```

Don't know about powershell, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can gather IE add-ons, using Powershell, by using the following:

```
  If (!(Test-Path HKCR:)) 
{ 
    New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT 
} 
$searchScopes = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Ext\Settings","HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\Browser Helper Objects" 
$searchScopes | Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select -ExpandProperty PSChildName |  
ForEach-Object { 
 If (Test-Path "HKCR:\CLSID\$_") { 
    Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKCR:\CLSID\$_" | Select-Object @{n="Name";e="(default)"} 
 } 
} | 
Sort-Object -Unique -Property Name
```

It will give you the name, but you can list other properties.

Credit - https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-export-a-list-of-IE-251948ba